# how to avoid lag when displaying a large String?

Tags: android, textview

In one of my apps I have to display the Terms of Service which is a kind of a huge HTML-formatted `String`. Displaying this `String` in a `TextView` causes a noticeable lag on mid- to high-end devices (Nexus 5, SGS 4) and an up to 4 seconds freeze on low-end devices.

I managed to reduce the frame drop by about 60% with help of a simple task to move HTML parsing off the main `Thread`:

```
public class FromHTMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Spanned> {

private OnHTMLParseCompleteListener listener;

public FromHTMLTask(OnHTMLParseCompleteListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface OnHTMLParseCompleteListener {
    void onHtmlParsed(Spanned text);
}

@Override
protected Spanned doInBackground(String... params) {
    return Html.fromHtml(params[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Spanned result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (listener != null)
        listener.onHtmlParsed(result);
 }
}
```

However, the `setText()` method itself causes a noticeable delay when displaying the processed text and the `Choreographer` still reports about 35 dropped frames on low-end devices.

Since I cannot call `setText()` from a background `Thread`, is there any way to avoid this lag **except of splitting the String into multiple parts and performing a lazy load**?

Comment: Use Traceview and determine exactly where your problem comes from inside the `setText()` call and related processing. My guess is that you cannot improve matters much, though getting rid of the formatting (and going with plain text) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextView` was not designed to show large texts. I suppose `WebView` should work much faster especially if you need to show html.

```
WebView webView;
String html;
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: this actually works faster and no frame drop is reported when using a `WebView`, thx for the hint

Answer (score 0):

In case you insist using a **TextView** , you can place it inside a **NestedScrollView**  for a better performance .

```
   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
     >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/about"
              />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```